# ServiceStack's JsConfig.TextCase no long honored in v6.0

Tags: servicestack

We have existing code that worked as desired in ServiceStack v5.13.2, but had unexpected breaking behavior after upgrading to v6.0.0.

Here is our service implementation:

```
public async Task<object> Get(IsAuthenticated request)
        {
            var session = await this.GetSessionAsync();

            bool isAuth = await AuthUserSessionExtensions.AuthenticateAsync(Request, Request.Dto);
            if (!isAuth) throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();

            var sanitizedSession = new AuthUserSession()
            {
                FirstName = session.FirstName,
                LastName = session.LastName,
                Email = session.Email,
                Permissions = session.Permissions,
                Roles = session.Roles,
                UserName = session.UserName,
            };

            return sanitizedSession;
        }
```

Originally, we would receive the response back in `camelCase`, per our JsConfig settings.  After upgrading, the `AuthUserSession` was ALWAYS in `PascalCase`.  Even wrapping a manual serialization in a JsConfig scope and explicitly requesting `camelCase`, serialization only ever provided Pascal.

Example output post-upgrade:

```
{
    "ReferrerUrl": null,
    "Id": null,
    "UserAuthId": "5",
    "UserAuthName": null,
    "UserName": "admin",
    "TwitterUserId": null,
}
```

My only thought is the ServiceStack v6 libraries perform special serialization for `AuthUserSession` and/or ServiceStack's own POCOs.

Comment: FYI more info in this [Customer Forums Post](https://forums.servicestack.net/t/camel-case-session-gone/10340?u=mythz), in MyGet 6.0.1+ now follows default case, i.e. uses camelCase for ASP .NET Core.

Comment: I’ve since reverted this behavior of using hard-coded names in the just released v6.0.2 on NuGet as there were a couple of reported issues. Apologies for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

A work-around is to create a custom POCO that matches field-for-field the `AuthUserSession`.  Serialization of our own classes works without issue.

```
public class CustomSession
    {
        public string UserAuthId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public List<string> Permissions { get; set; }
        public List<string> Roles { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }
```

results in the properly serialized output:

```
{
    "userAuthId": "5",
    "firstName": "Admin",
    "lastName": "Admin",
    "email": "admin@",
...
```